# $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{g(x)}\Rightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{2^x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{g(x)}{2^x}}$?

Tags: analysis

Is this statement true? Why?
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} =\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{g(x)} \quad  \Rightarrow\quad \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{2^x}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{g(x)}{2^x}}$$

Comment: Do you mean  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{g(x)} \Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{2^x}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{g(x)}{2^x}}$?

Comment: You should also include that in the question title

Comment: In $\LaTeX$: \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{g(x)} \Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(x)}{2^x}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{g(x)}{2^x}}

Comment: @user3491648 you're right. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't true. The problem is that from $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ you can't tell *how fast* $f$ tends to infinity. For example, consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2^x$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} x = +\infty = \lim_{x \to +\infty} 2^x
$$
but
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x}{2^x} = 0 \neq 1 = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{2^x}{2^x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely no. Think of 2 functions which tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$...

Comment: As stated, this is more of a comment than an answer. To make it a proper answer you should better clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

When is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\rightarrow g(x)$ true?

If I substitute it with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)-g(x) \rightarrow 0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/2^{x} \rightarrow g(x)/2^{x}$ is trivially true. Because you can't really say $\infty=\infty$, just add the condition that both $f$ and $g$ converge at $\infty$ to satisfy $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/2^{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)/2^{x}$.

Comment: What can we say if we supposed  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{2x}→\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(x)}{2x}$?

Comment: I doesn't matter what you divide it by so long as you avoid singularities.